# How to interrupt standard input stream for another

Tags: c, input, stream, stdin

This problem maybe a little bit hard to state. For example, a program receive a string from `stdin`, but it need a interactive input from user, like this:

```
echo "Some text to handle later after command is specified" | a.out
```

And in the beginning of the program:

```
printf("Please input command first");
scanf("%s", &cmd);
/* Some Code Here */
/* process "Some text to handle later after command is specified" */
```

Is there a way to "suspend" previous input stream and wait for the `scanf`'s ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard does not specify any way to get interactive user input besides reading from stdin. Since your stdin is occupied with a pipe, you need to tread an implementation-specific path.

For Unix-like systems that would be a special file named `/dev/tty`.  `fopen` it and use normal stdio functions.

On Windows you probably need to call Console API.

Threre's no guarantee a program is attached to any interactive device, so prepare to fail.

Note that it's considered bad style to write programs this way. If there's any user input expected, a well-witten program should just use stdin. All other input streams should then be passed as filenames via command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When using pipes, the shell sets up the programs `stdin` to be from the output of the previous command. So reading should not be a problem.

The problem here is that you should not print any output if the input is from a pipe (or redirection). This can be done by checking the result of the [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) function:

```
if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
{
    /* Only print prompt if input is an interactive terminal */
    printf(...);
}

scanf(...);
```

---

Or am I misreading you, in that you want to read *both* from the user, *and* from the pipe? Then you probably have to open a direct connection to the terminal.

For this you could use [`ttyname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ttyname.html) to get the name of the TTY device of `stdout` and open that device for input to read the user input. That won't work if the `stdout` is leading to a pipe (or is being redirected) as well.